# Consequences of the completeness of equational logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, universal-algebra

It is a classical result, due to Birkhoff, that equational logic is complete; that is, if $\Sigma$ is a classical (finitary) signature in the sense of universal algebra and $s, t$ are terms constructed from variables and the operation symbols of $\Sigma$, then the equation $s = t$ is deducible from a set of equations $E$ (using the standard rules of equational reasoning) if and only if the equation $s = t$ is entailed by $E$, i.e. is satisfied by every $\Sigma$-algebra that satisfies all equations of $E$.

My question is: what are the useful consequences of the completeness of equational logic? I suppose that one useful consequence would be its compactness, i.e. that if $s = t$ is entailed by a set of equations $E$, then it is entailed by a finite subset of $E$. What are some other (significant) useful consequences of knowing that equational logic is complete?

Comment: Perhaps philosophically, completness tells us that the axiomatic approach to algebra "works" in the sense that we can prove some equation about abelian groups (say) if and only if that equation is true in every abelian group!

Comment: In this instance, it depends on what kinds of consequences one seeks. See for [a nice paragraph](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Equational_logic#:~:text=In%20this%20way,Poincar%C3%A9%20and%20Hilbert.) that offers pointers to philosophical ramifications.